# MultiButton setTextLine3 not showing

Tags: codenameone

In my code i'm setting

`MultiButton mb = new MultiButton(myText1);`

`mb.setTextLine2(myText2);`

`mb.setTextLine3(myText3);`

only the two lines are showing, my Text3 is not

myText1

myText2

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. I'm guessing your background is the same color as the label color or something like that:

```
Form current = new Form("MultiButton", BoxLayout.y());

MultiButton mb = new MultiButton("Line 1...");
mb.setTextLine2("Line 2...");
mb.setTextLine3("Line 3...");
current.add(mb);
current.show();
```

[image]